# Self Incrementing Value In Oracle Query

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm new to Oracle DB...

I have a table consisting of 2 fields, YEAR and MAINT_CODE.

I have to write a report query which will render the following in a report:

```
 ACTION  | YEAR | MAINT_CODE
--------------------------
Action 1 | 2012 | 0123
Action 2 | 2012 | 0122
Action 3 | 2013 | 0122
```

Now, I do not have an Action field, this number after Action must just increment.
I cannot alter the table at all.

My current query looks like this:

```
SELECT YEAR, MAINT_CODE
FROM mytable
```

How can I get that incrementing value after the Action?
I'm not even sure where to look - I've looked into sequencing but I'm not sure that's what I need here. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT 'Action '||to_char(row_number() over (order by year, maint_code)) as action,
       YEAR, 
       MAINT_CODE
FROM mytable
order by year, maint_code
```

You have to have an order otherwise the "sequence" does not make sense, that's why I have applied an `order by year, maint_code` to generate the `row_number()` and sort the overall result with the same sort definition.

Comment: Just for my education, was there a way to use `ROWNUM` instead?